# c++ regex substring wrong pattern found

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to understand the logic on the `regex` in c++

```
std::string s ("Ni Ni Ni NI");
std::regex e ("(Ni)");

std::smatch sm;  
std::regex_search (s,sm,e);
std::cout << "string object with " << sm.size() << " matches\n";
```

This form shouldn't give me the number of substrings matching my pattern? Because it always give me 1 match and it says that the match is `[Ni , Ni];` but i need it to find every single pattern; they should be 3 and like this `[Ni][Ni][Ni]`

Comment: You forgot to match the whitespaces.

Comment: I've tried using \b as word boundary but it doesn'y work

Comment: Neither the global flag \(Ni)\g works

Comment: Did you already try something like `"((Ni)[ ]+)+"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function [std::regex_search](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) only returns the results for the first match found in your string.

Here is a code, merged from yours and from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/). The idea is to search for the first match, analyze it, and then start again using the rest of the string (that is to say, the sub-string that directly follows the match that was found, which can be retrieved thanks to [match_results::suffix](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results/suffix) ).

Note that the regex has two capturing groups `(Ni*)` and `([^ ]*)`.

```
std::string s("the knights who say Niaaa and Niooo");
std::smatch m;
std::regex e("(Ni*)([^ ]*)");

while (std::regex_search(s, m, e))
{
    for (auto x : m)
        std::cout << x.str() << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
    s = m.suffix().str();
}
```

This gives the following output:

> Niaaa Ni aaa
>
> Niooo Ni ooo

As you can see, for every call to regex_search, we have the following information:

- the content of the whole match,
- the content of every capturing group.

Since we have two capturing groups, this gives us 3 strings for every regex_search.

**EDIT**: in your case if you want to retrieve every "Ni", all you need to do is to replace

```
std::regex e("(Ni*)([^ ]*)");
```

with

```
std::regex e("(Ni)");
```

You still need to iterate over your string, though.

Comment: what if I need to find the specific substring 'Ni' only? also this regex it's case insensitive; using my previous string it gives wrong results

Comment: well you simply need to use the regex you already had : "(Ni)" (instead of "(Ni*)([^ ]*)" in my example). The only difference with your code is that you need to iterate over your string to find every "Ni". The case sensitivity depends on the flags you use. Have a look at the regex_search 4th param.